# Most efficient way to do simple Entity API queries by node id and content type?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

A very basic 8.x API question.

What is the approved/simplest methods of confirming a node matching a certain content type and ID exists, and then loading it as an object?

(Use case: a module which accepts a node ID in the URL, that needs to be checked.)

Currently I have:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load(123);

if ($node->getType() == 'application') {
  return $node;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

My first attempt was in reserve (longer/less efficient):

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'application')
  ->condition('nid', 123)
  ->execute();

// followed by entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node') etc.
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to make entityQueue() return a **flat** array of IDs rather than an associative `[1=>1,2=>2,3=>3]` which you then have to mess around with.

Comment: Is this always a node argument? You could upcast the argument in your route to node and have the object available in the Request, without having to do an entityQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how your module URL/API is structured, but if your module route has something like `myapi/foo/bar/(id)` to return a node object, you could upcast it instead. Here is an example from the node module:

```
entity.node.version_history:
  path: '/node/{node}/revisions'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Revisions'
    _controller: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::revisionOverview'
  requirements:
    node: \d+
```

`{node}` will be upcast to a node object and available in the incoming request to the receiving class.

See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/using-parameters-in-routes

So when you pass that to the receiving method:

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

class ExampleController {
  public function foo(NodeInterface $node) {
    if ($node->getType() != 'application') {
      // do something, throw Exception, etc?
    } 

    // Otherwise this node is an application type.
    return $node;
  }
}
```

There may be a way to expand on this in the route definition, so you can upcast the node *and* ensure it is a specific type before doing anything else, eliminating the checking in the method - but I am not sure.

Perhaps:

- https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/requirements.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/conditions.html

Comment: thanks, excellent answer. I've got that working now, and with a _form rather than a generic controller. (Crucial bit, for others reading, is the parameter must be called 'node' in the route, so it works with NodeInterface.)  From reading docs, I'm not sure you *can* check the type in the routing without writing your own paramconverter...

Comment: @WilliamTurrell You're right, you'd need to write your own parameter converter to also check the type. It's trivial though, only a few lines of code

Answer (score 2):

> What is the approved/simplest methods of confirming a node matching a certain content type and ID exists, and then loading it as an object?

I could easily be wrong, but I'm not sure there is one, really. It depends how you define "simplest".

Personally I'd test the object type first:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load(123);
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\Entity\Node && $node->getType() == 'application') {

}
```

If you're just talking about performance between the two different approaches, then yes, the first approach is better as it requires at most one query, whereas the second requires two.

> rather than an associative [1=>1,2=>2,3=>3] which you then have to mess around with.

I'm not sure what you mean by that; an associative array is exactly the same as a "flat" array in that example - just ignore the keys or values as required.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this:

```
$nid = 123;
$type = 'application';
$node_exists = (bool) db_query('SELECT 1 FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid AND type = :type', [':nid' => $nid, ':type' => $type)->fetchField();

if ($node_exists) {
  return node_load($nid);
}

return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [EntityStorageBase::loadByProperties](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.5.x), because it's flexible and lightweight in my eyes. It returns an array, so you can use [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to get the node if exists:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties([          
  'nid' => $nid,
  'type' => 'application'
]);
if ($node = reset($nodes)) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Combine this with a custom param converter and I think we have a winner...

Comment: Actually, this internally does an entity query *and* loading the node. Just doing a load() is clearly more efficient here, especially of the node is already in the persistent or even static cache